# Click button to go to another page

Tags: android, button

What is the wrong with this code ? it should open the first page for the button then go to the next page to view the images ?

GameView class to view images

MainActivity Class

```
package com.example.abc; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(new GameView(this));

    }
}
```

//Button Class

```
public class Button extends Activity {
    ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent("MainActivity");
                 startActivity(intent);  

            }
        });

    }
}
```

//The Manifest code

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.abc.MainActivity2"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainActivity2" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: can you provide what the logs say

Comment: Why are you Making the Button Extend Activity?

Comment: i make a game, the first page has an ImageButton "play" i do it in xml , so after clicking play it should go to the next page to view the game

Comment: i guess the problem in setContentView(new GameView(this)); , because when i run it open the page of the gameview not the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.abc.MainActivity2"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="youPackageNameHere.MainActivity2" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

```
       <activity
    android:name="com.example.abc.Button"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

and while setting up an intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("yourPackageNamehere.MainActivity");
                 startActivity(intent);
```

Hope that solved your error

Answer (score 0):

if to tell you what i think it can be 2 things:

1. the second activity is not defined in the manifest.
   I can see only 1 activity, i can't know if you wrote them both or replaced 1.
   although, i can see MainActivity2 and not Button class so i think this will cause an error.
2. the intent is written wrong.
   i really hate to use all of the ways because it is hard for me to write it right.
   try to do so:

   Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   startIntent(i);

if you meant that it is opening the MainActivity instead of the Button it because you need to define the Button activity in the manifest as LAUNCHER instead of DEFAULT, and change the MainActivity to DEFAULT

EDIT:
i just saw that you have the same xml in both of them.
what xml file contain the image?
you need to set MainActivity with this xml and not main_activity

Comment: i defined both MainActivity and Button , and in Manifast i defined the Button as LAUNCHER too , but in MainActivity when i add "setContentView(new GameView(this));" it run the 2nd page "gameview" not the first page "button" , but if i removed "setContentView(new GameView(this));" it show the button only

Comment: you want the button and the game to run together?

Comment: the button run first then the game

Comment: i think i understood. you did setContentPane(new GameView(this)) in the Button class or in the MainActivity class? it could go ot the MainActivity

Comment: i did it in the MainActivity

Comment: oh, i see now. i thought you putted the first code. you have 2 setContentView. delete the first one, it should fix it